# how to set more than rows to pojo class variables using jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am new to Spring, I am trying to fetch the data from table and set to pojo class like below code using spring jdbcTemplate,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdevicedata/{macId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public DeviceAnalyse getDevicedata(@PathVariable String macId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        DeviceAnalyse deviceAnalyse = new DeviceAnalyse();
        //List<DeviceAnalyse> deviceAnalyse = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!isValidMacId(macId)) {
            deviceAnalyse.setDId("Invalid device Id");
            return deviceAnalyse;

        }
        DeviceAnalyse temp = new DeviceAnalyse();
        try{
                    temp = new DeviceAnalyse();
                    String sql = "select value,serverTimeStamp,sensorType,percentage from tablename";
                    temp = (DeviceAnalyse)jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{macId}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(DeviceAnalyse.class));
                    deviceAnalyse.setPercentage(temp.getPercentage());
                    deviceAnalyse.setSensorType(temp.getSensorType());
                    deviceAnalyse.setServerTimeStamp(temp.getServerTimeStamp());
                    deviceAnalyse.setValue(temp.getValue());

        }
        catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    deviceAnalyse.setPercentage(0L);
                    deviceAnalyse.setSensorType("");
                    deviceAnalyse.setServerTimeStamp(null);
                    deviceAnalyse.setValue(0L);
        }

        return deviceAnalyse;
    }
```

here DeviceAnalyse  is my pojo class which have all getter setter. but i am getting **Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 4**.

How to fix this and set all retrieving values to pojo class? like

```
while(resultset.next())
{
   deviceAnalyse.setPercentage(temp.getPercentage());
   deviceAnalyse.setSensorType(temp.getSensorType());
   deviceAnalyse.setServerTimeStamp(temp.getServerTimeStamp());                                      
   deviceAnalyse.setValue(temp.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You made one simple mistake in your code. You should call `jdbcTemplate.query` instead of `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject`.

[`jdbcTemplate.queryForObject`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L796) expects exactly one row in the result because `RowMapperResultSetExtractor` becomes initialized with `1`. Instead [`jdbcTemplate.query`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L772) returns all rows.

Don't forget to change your `temp` variable to `List<DeviceAnalyse>`.

Calling `jdbcTemplate` may look like this:

```
List<DeviceAnalyse> temp = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{macId}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(DeviceAnalyse.class));
```